# Partially merge two Git branches

Tags: git

I see git repos for tutorials with branches corresponding to each chapter of the tutorial.
So in chapter one for example the tutorial is teaching how to create the home page, in chapter 2 how to connect it to the back end.

Chapter 1 has a chapter1 branch in the git repo that only has the main page

Chapter 2 has chapter2 branch that has the main page + the script that calls the API , and so on.

Now let's say that at one point (chapter 3) we want to change the colors and styles for the home page, and we want that reflected in all the branches for chapter1, chapter2 and 3.

Merging the changes to styles that was made in chapter 3 will also merge all the changes back to chapter1 not, so chapter1 and chapter3 branches will be identical. Which we don't want.

is there other way to do that other than manually copying and pasting the required changes?

Comment: Do the modification on chapter 1 branch on merge on all branches.
Other way have chapter 1 has a submodule instead of a branch

Comment: Are you asking how to merge changes only to certain files from another branch?

Comment: Consider cherry-picking the change from chapter3 branch into chapter2 and chapter1 branches, if they are similar enough.

Comment: @Ôrel thanks, this is the first way described in the accepted answer

Comment: @DMalan there could be changes made  within a file from a branch to branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish what you're describing.  Merging `chapter3` into earlier chapters isn't one of them.  (You can sort of approximate the idea of "me3rging only some files", but it's pretty manual and can lead to errors.  It's also worth noting that in most tutorials, a later chapter could modify a file that was introduced in a previous chapter, so merging file-by-file wouldn't necessarily work anyway.)

So what you have is something like this:

```
O -- x -- x <--(chapter1)
           \
            x -- x <--(chapter2)
                  \
                   x -- x -- x <--(chapter3)
```

The simplest way is to change the colors on the `chapter1` branch and then merge them forward.

This would give you a history like

```
O -- x -- x --------------- A <--(chapter1)
           \                 \
            x -- x ---------- M1 <--(chapter2)
                  \             \
                   x -- x -- x - M2 <--(chapter3)
```

This is going to be the easiest way; it's the natural way to use branches and merges to do what you want to do.  Everything else is going to be about trying to get the same effect with a history that looks different from this picture, possibly at the expense of some manual steps.

If you just don't want the merge commits, you could use the `--squash` option when merging the change forward from `chapter1` to the other branches.  This would give you something like

```
O -- x -- x -- A <--(chapter1)
           \
            x -- x -- A' <--(chapter2)
                  \
                   x -- x -- x - A'' <--(chapter3)
```

You could get similar effects by cherry picking or rebasing the added commit.  The down side to this is, git doesn't "know" that `chapter2` and `chapter3` include the changes from `A`.  So if you go back and add changes to `chapter1` a second time, and want to propagate those forward as well, it's possible you'll get unnecessary merge conflicts.

A third approach is to rewrite history so that it "looks like" the changes had been there before the other chapter branches were created.  While I generally am not a huge fan of rewriting history for cosmetic reasons, in the case where a repo's history is supposed to track progress through a tutorial, it's a fairly reasonable option.  The history, in this context, is arguably part of the content you're producing, so of course it may be subject to revision.

How best to do such a rewrite depends on how complex the repo is.

It could be simple to do as a series of rebases (if everything is very linear).  (That is, you might check out `O`, make your changes, commit with `--amend`, then rebase `chapter1` to the amended commit, then rebase `chapter2`, etc.

If that's too many steps, or if the repo is more complex, then something like `filter-repo` coudl be used to rewrite the whole history at once.

Comment: Thanks @MarkAdelsberger for the detailed and informative answer